# Google doesn't approve the builtin "Search Engine Sitemap"?

Tags: 2013

In SharePoint 2013 there is a built in feature called "Search Engine Sitemap" that builds sitemap.xml files in the siteroot.

The files looks like this

sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Generated: 2014-11-09T20:10:00-->
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://www.herlitz.nu:80/sitemap0.xml</loc>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://www.herlitz.nu:80/sitemap_mobile0.xml</loc>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Sitemap0.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Generated: 2014-11-09T20:10:00-->
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.herlitz.nu:80/2014/11/05/restoring-a-backed-up-site-collection-with-managed-navigation-in-another-web-application</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-11-09T18:21:07Z</lastmod>
  </url>
...
```

Google webmaster tools returns this error

> This required tag is missing. Please add it and resubmit.

According to this documentation I think it looks good, https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I validated the file using validator.w3.org and received the error

> Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 1 it
>   contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as us-ascii (in
>   other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified
>   Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the
>   character encoding indication. '

When digging a bit it seems as if SharePoint return XML with the response content type `text/xml` and not `text/xml;charset=utf-8`

After replacing this using URL Rewrite everything is alive and kicking